# Python Script can't detect a file in the same folder

Tags: python, file, initialization, python-3.5, file-handling

I have a program, `api.py`, that includes this section of code:

```
face_detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()

#predictor_model = face_recognition_models.pose_predictor_model_location()
pose_predictor = dlib.shape_predictor('shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')

#face_recognition_model = face_recognition_models.face_recognition_model_location()
face_encoder = dlib.face_recognition_model_v1("dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat")
```

And whenever I try to run it, by importing it from another file, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "00--storeFaceEmbds.py", line 5, in <module>
    import corecode
  File "//home/jason/Code/Projects/FR/Projects/corecode/api.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .api import load_image_file, face_locations, face_landmarks, face_encodings, compare_faces, face_distance
  File "/home/jason/Code/Projects/FR/Projects/corecode/api.py", line 19, in <module>
    pose_predictor = dlib.shape_predictor('shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')
RuntimeError: Unable to open shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat
```

Which doesn't make sense, because it's in the same folder as the file:

```
ls -al
total 119412
drwxrwxrwx 5 jason jason     4096 Nov 28 23:23 .
drwxrwxrwx 6 jason jason     4096 Nov 28 22:27 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jason jason     6816 Nov 28 23:23 api.py
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jason jason     8390 May 19  2017 api.pyc
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jason jason     2468 May  1  2017 cli.py
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jason jason 22466066 Mar  6  2017 dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat
drwxrwxrwx 3 jason jason     4096 May 20  2017 face_recognition_models
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jason jason      224 Sep 10 02:12 __init__.py
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jason jason      518 May 19  2017 __init__.pyc
drwxrwxrwx 2 jason jason     4096 Nov 28 22:29 models
drwxrwxr-x 2 jason jason     4096 Nov 28 23:23 __pycache__
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jason jason 99693937 Mar  6  2017 shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat
```

What could be happening here?

Comment: Have you tried adding "." before file name?

Comment: pose_predictor = dlib.shape_predictor('.shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')

Comment: Just tried: `RuntimeError: Unable to open .shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat`. No-go.

Comment: Try using the absolute path to the file. If that does not work, make sure the file is not opened or in use by another program.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the absolute path"? It's in the same folder.

Comment: The full path to the file - even if it is in the same folder. Like: "//home/path/to/file.dat"

It's worth it to do this simple test to troubleshoot your issue.,